# Cell ranges export as images, without white border

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba to export several cell ranges in same work sheet as images. Though task is being done perfectly with the below code but all the images are exported with a white thin border. I've already already inserted the what should remove the border but that does not work. My code is as follows

```
Dim oWs As Worksheet
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oChrtO As ChartObject
Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long
Set oWs = Sheets("sheet2")

oWs.Select
Set oRng = oWs.Range("g35:i44")
oRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lWidth = oRng.width
lHeight = oRng.height
Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, width:=lWidth, 
height:=lHeight)
oChrtO.Activate
With oChrtO.Chart
.ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
.Paste
.Export Filename:="C:\Users\tg033980\Desktop\JSS 
 project\img\MNTH1_A.png", Filtername:="PNG"
 End With
 oChrtO.Delete`
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide a sample image, so people can see what you're talking about

Comment: a picture in a chart does not fill it completely, so you see the `ChartArea` color around the outside of the picture, the color is white. If you want it to be black you can place this line `.ChartArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)` directly under `With oChrtO.Chart`. Or you can use `.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse` to  make the `ChartArea` transparent.